# pfsense squid proxy is blocking some sites

Tags: pfsense

I am not expert in pfsense firewall. Though I have pfsense 2.6.0 installed with squid & squidguard. Also i have configured target catagories in SquidGuard. All is working as per my configuration but some websites are not working. when i disable squid proxy that blocked websites working fine. in that case all the unwanted websites also unblocked. I want to use internet access through squid proxy only. but When i use squid proxy some websites that i want to use is also blocked. How to allow blocked websites through squid proxy.